# Template Haskell: Generate Records

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

With Template Haskell I would like to generate records, eg:

```
data MyRecordA = MyRecordA
  {fooA :: String, barA :: Bool}
```

The uppercase *A* in *MyRecordA*, *fooA*, *barA* and the type *Bool* of the second field should be variable and specified by the caller of the TH function.

I tried with several variations of:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module THRecord where
import Language.Haskell.TH

mkRecord :: Name -> Name -> Q [Dec] 
mkRecord name cls = [d|
  data $typeName :: $constName 
    {$fieldFoo, $fieldBar}
  |]
  where
    typeName = conT  $ "MyRecord" <> name
    constrName = RecC $ "MyRecord" <> name
    fieldFoo = sigP name ($clsString)
    fieldBar = sigP name cls
    clsString = conT "String"
```

Unfortunately, I get parse errors like

> src/THRecord.hs:8:9: error: parse error on input ‘$fieldFoo’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues here; lets look at them one by one. The splice you have:

```
[d|
  data $typeName :: $constName 
    {$fieldFoo, $fieldBar}
  |]
```

is simply not valid; you may only splice entire expressions, types, or declarations, and not parts thereof. You also probably meant `data $typeName = $constName` but of course the same restriction applies to that, so it still won't work.

---

The definition

```
fieldFoo = sigP name ($clsString)
```

doesn't work because you may not have an splice of a local variable without an intervening quote. This is known as the 'stage restriction'.

---

```
fieldFoo = sigP name ($clsString)
fieldBar = sigP name cls
```

`sigP` is wrong because it constructs a pattern; you don't need to build any patterns (not sure what you meant here).

---

```
typeName = conT  $ "MyRecord" <> name
constrName = RecC $ "MyRecord" <> name
clsString = conT "String"
```

All of these are trying to treat a `Name` as a `String`. If it isn't clear why that doesn't make sense, perhaps you should familiarize yourself with the basics of Haskell.

---

Now the solution:

```
import Data.Monoid
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax

defBang = Bang NoSourceUnpackedness NoSourceStrictness
stringType = ConT ''String

mkRecord :: Name -> Name -> Q [Dec] 
mkRecord name cls = (pure.pure)$
  DataD [] typeName [] Nothing [constr] []
  where
    typeName = mkName $ "MyRecord" <> nameBase name
    constr = RecC typeName [(mkName $ "foo" <> nameBase name, defBang, stringType)
                           ,(mkName $ "bar" <> nameBase name, defBang, ConT cls)]
```

Note that you don't even make use of the `Q` monad here; not to generate names, nor to reify info about names. Therefore you can actually write a function `Name -> Name -> Dec` and then applying `pure.pure` to the result produces a type which can be spliced.

The above is for GHC 8.0.1; the AST of Template Haskell varies significantly between majour releases so it may not compile exactly as is on other versions.

Then e.g.

```
$(mkRecord (mkName "XYZ") ''Bool)
$(mkRecord (mkName "A") ''Int)
```

produces

```
data MyRecordXYZ = MyRecordXYZ {fooXYZ :: String, barXYZ :: Bool}
data MyRecordA = MyRecordA {fooA :: String, barA :: Int}
```

---

Finally, here is a solution which doesn't require TH. The family of types you wish to generate can be represented in a first class way:

```
import GHC.TypeLits

data MyRecord (nm :: Symbol) t = MyRecord { foo :: String, bar :: t }

type MyRecordA = MyRecord "A" Bool
type MyRecordXYZ = MyRecord "XYZ" Int
```

Comment: I specially like the solution without TH!

Comment: Unfortunately the nice TH-free solution has a little quirk: It doesn't generate different names for the data constructor. It generates always *MyRecord* and not *MyRecordA* and *MyRecordXYZ*

Comment: @Jogger Indeed, but that doesn't really cost you anything. You can still restrict the type of the constructor to any name, e.g. `MyRecord :: String -> t -> MyRecord "X" t`. With `-XTypeApplications` you can even write ` MyRecord @"X"`